# store mysql query in another table using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MySQL table `feedback`.

[image: Mysql Table]

I want to calculate average of every column and store the result to table `average` as below structure using a PHP file.

[image]

I am using query `SELECT AVG (waiting) FROM feedback` to calculate average of waiting column. But I do not have any idea of how to put this query result to another table as the above structure.

When using query `INSERT INTO average (average) SELECT AVG (waiting) FROM feedback` **it only updating the average column.

Please help me with a sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand you correctly you can do it like this

```sql
INSERT INTO average (data, average)
SELECT 'waiting',      AVG (waiting)      FROM feedback UNION ALL
SELECT 'consultation', AVG (consultation) FROM feedback UNION ALL
SELECT 'preoperative', AVG (preoperative) FROM feedback
```

Sample output:

```
|         DATA | AVERAGE |
--------------------------
|      waiting |       3 |
| consultation |       2 |
| preoperative |       3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18835/1)** demo

---

Now if you don't have lots of data in `feedback` table you can ditch `average` table and create a view with the same way. As a result instead of maintaining a table of averages they will be calculated on the fly when you select from it

```sql
CREATE VIEW average AS 
SELECT 'waiting',   ROUND(AVG (waiting)) average FROM feedback UNION ALL
SELECT 'consultation', ROUND(AVG (consultation)) FROM feedback UNION ALL
SELECT 'preoperative', ROUND(AVG (preoperative)) FROM feedback
```

And use it

```sql
SELECT * FROM average
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/782d4/1)** demo

Comment: it returns this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Did you ditched `...` from the end of the query? It meant that you can continue to add other averages as you need. See my sqlfiddle example that I provided.

Comment: You don't need an extra `UNION ALL` at the end. Delete it and try again, please.

Comment: Perfect. Now I hope I can use this query from a php everytime user updates the feedback database. Actually I want to show this average data as a googlegraph.

Comment: Your second suggestion is a very good option, but I think it will not be useful in my solution. As I want to call the data from average table from a separate php to show the data as a graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the result from the average of each column and then INSERT that into a separate database.

What you are doing now inserts it into the same column in the same database, not a different one, which is why it's just updating that column and not a different one.

Example of an INSERT query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES ($averageOfColumn)";
```

Replace 'tableName' with the name of the new table you are connecting to.

Replace 'columnName' with the name of the column in the other database you are using.

Replace '$averageOfColumn' with your variable for the average of the waiting column.

Does this help?

Comment: @PeeJay great. Make sure to create a separate table!

Comment: Sure Sir. Its late here, So I will definitely answer you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

To get average values for those three columns:

```
SELECT AVG(waiting),AVG(consultation),AVG(preoperative) FROM feedback;
```

To insert to average table, if column names are the same:

```
INSERT INTO average(waiting,consultation,preoperative) 
SELECT AVG(waiting),AVG(consultation),AVG(preoperative) FROM feedback
```